# How can I access a value of a variable inside a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app I am populating table rows with data from an array.

Below, I want to be able to access the value of the notes variable when the year `td`is clicked

```
rows.map((row) => {
                        return <tr key={row.id}>
                            <td>{row.start}</td>
                            <td>{row.end}</td>
                            <td  onClick={(row) => console.log(row.year)}>{row.year}</td>
                            <td>{row.notes}</td>
                            <td/></td>
                        </tr>
                    })
```

When I click this `td` which has 1999 on screen `undefined` is output to the console.

Can someone help me understand how I can access this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code fails, **why?**

```
rows.map((row) => {
                        return <tr key={row.id}>
                            <td>{row.start}</td>
                            <td>{row.end}</td>
                            <td  onClick={(row) => console.log(row.year)}>{row.year}</td>
                            <td>{row.notes}</td>
                            <td/></td>
                        </tr>
                    })
```

concretely, `onClick={(row) => console.log(row.year)}`

You are assuming that when you do click you get `row` as a parameter in the onClick callback, what you get there is the event. So, your `row` param is an event which does not have `year` for that reason you see `undefined`.

**Solution**:

Just remove `row`.

`onClick={(clickEvent) => console.log(row.year)}`

In your arrow function, you have access to the `row` object.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like so:

```
accessNotes(notes) {
console.log(notes)
}
```

And in your Html do like this:

```
rows.map((row) => {
                    return <tr key={row.id}>
                        <td>{row.start}</td>
                        <td>{row.end}</td>
                         // You don't need to pass row
                        <td  onClick={() => {
                                      console.log(row.year);
                                      // here you call the function
                                      this.accessNotes(row.notes)
                                       }}>{row.year}</td>
                        <td>{row.notes}</td>
                        <td/></td>
                    </tr>
                })
```

Comment: You now have two different contexts for `row`. The one in `onClick` is the event

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing the year on event object rather than the row. The first argument passed to `onClick` function is the event object which you have also named row ( also known as shadowing ). Name it something else like event or e or simply omit it if you don't want to access the event. Do this.

```
rows.map((row) => {
    return <tr key={row.id}>
        <td>{row.start}</td>
        <td>{row.end}</td>

        <td onClick={(e) => console.log(row.year)}>{row.year}</td>

        <td>{row.notes}</td>
        <td/></td>
    </tr>
})
```

Hope this helps !